# Запятые вокруг "и"

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли я расставила здесь запятые? В частности, смущает постановка запятых вокруг союза "и", хотя все правила понимаю...

В России сегодня необходимо идти путем наших европейских партнеров и развивать производство и комплектацию, охватывая как можно больше типов и видов трубопроводной арматуры, деталей трубопроводов, опор труб, и, возможно, уже сейчас надо включать в номенклатуру отдельные типы трубной продукции.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо идти и развивать и надо включать. Перед И нет запятой.

Comment: А я подумала, что надо выделить деепричастный оборот "охватывая как можно больше типов и видов трубопроводной арматуры" и не поняла, что дальше там просто однородные члены, а сам деепричастный оборот заканчивается раньше (не после "труб").

Comment: Верно, я не прав. Деепричастный оборот заканчивается как раз после труб.